# Can the return of a promise be used as an input for the next function call in a Promise.all() execution?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, memoization

I've been looked on StackOverflow and haven't seen any direct examples of what I'm asking. I'm reading this article on memoization [link here](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/async-javascript-is-much-more-fun-when-you-spend-less-time-thinking-about-control-flow-8580ce9f73fc) if you want to look.

It appears to me that you should be able to run them all together and use the return value from getSoupRecipe() as input for hireSoupChef()

```
async function makeSoupFromType(soupType) {
    
    let [ soupRecipe, soupPan, soupChef ] = await Promise.all([
        
        getSoupRecipe(soupType),
        buySoupPan(),
        hireSoupChef(soupRecipe.requiredSkills)
    ]);
    
    return await makeSoup(soupChef, soupRecipe, soupPan);
}
```

**So the question is can all three async functions run at the same time and *once* getSoupRecipe returns I use it's variable name (***which is soupRecipe***) as input for hireSoupChef.**

*I would post all the other code here for you to see but I think it would probably make the question look too daunting, so the link is above. You don't necessarily have to look at it to understand I don't think because I think I've stated the question right, but nonetheless if you want to you can.*

Comment: `So the question is can all three async functions run at the same time and once getSoupRecipe returns I use it's variable name (which is soupRecipe) as input for hireSoupChef.` No, by definition one can't run __at the same time__ as another one if one requires the others result as input. Thats what chaining was made for

Comment: Your question contains the answer: **run at the same time and once getSoupRecipe returns** -- it's NOT the same time.

Comment: Does promise.all() not run them all together?, similar to how multi-threaded stuff works. And okay whether they're run *all* at the same time or not, can you do this. Can you use the return from one in the input of another in the context of Promise.all

Comment: Promise.all() runs them, but does not resolve/reject until all have resolved or one has rejected.

Comment: @RandyCasburn What would be the appropriate infrastructure? I'm not having a problem, more as a need for clarification of how it works

Comment: OK, next time please consider stating that purpose for the question. It would be helpful for shallow thinkers like me :-) Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The appropriate infrastructure just meant that everything (we can't see) actually returns promises, but you don't really have an issue with the code working, so that doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: @RandyCasburn But can the resolving of one be used in another,  say I wrote it with hireSoupChef(soupRecipe.requiredSkills) first then getSoupRecipe(soupType)... Would hireSoupChef sit around not knowing what to do, and then once getSoupRecipe is there, then hireSoupChef works. Especially because the variable that represents the return of getSoupType is outside of this scope isnt it (bc its not in the Promise.All) so was wondering if one could use that

Comment: As Bergi said, NO - it cannot. you've got to chain them. As I said, `Promise.All()` does not resolve _until they are all resolved_ OR _until one of them rejects_. So no, you cannot use one of the values prior to the others being available.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Oh okay, so because Promise.All() hasn't resolved yet that would mean it's variables [ soupRecipe, soupPan, soupChef ] have also not been set yet so even more so could never be used as inputs. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Yes, exactly! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by itself, no. In your example the `soupRecipe` (and the other two variables) are only initialised after the `Promise.all(…)` has been `await`ed, so it can't be used in the expressions that are passed to `Promise.all` as an argument. There's no magic going on here, `Promise.all` is not part of the syntax but really just returning one promise that fulfills with an array *once*.

However, the approach outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250704/1048572) to [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) does enable the desired chaining of asynchronous actions:

```
async function makeSoupFromType(soupType) {
    const soupRecipePromise = getSoupRecipe(soupType);
    const [soupRecipe, soupPan, soupChef] = await Promise.all([
        soupRecipePromise,
        buySoupPan(),
        soupRecipePromise.then(({requiredSkills}) => hireSoupChef(requiredSkills))
    ]);
    
    return makeSoup(soupChef, soupRecipe, soupPan);
}
```

Alternatively, with plain `async`/`await` you could also use an IIFE to avoid the `then()` call:

```
async function makeSoupFromType(soupType) {
    const [soupPan, [soupRecipe, soupChef]] = await Promise.all([
        buySoupPan(),
        (async () => {
            const soupRecipe = await getSoupRecipe(soupType);
            const soupChef = await hireSoupChef(soupRecipe.requiredSkills);
            return [soupRecipe, soupChef];
        })(),
    ]);
    
    return makeSoup(soupChef, soupRecipe, soupPan);
}
```

Comment: so Promise.all() runs concurrently, meaning they all run at once right (?), it's just the variables aren't initalised until the whole thing returns

Comment: @ArrSky76 No, running them concurrently (with `buySoupPan()`) is of course faster than running it sequentially after or before that. "*A couple other people commented saying they didn't run all at the same time*" - that's not what they said. What they said is that you don't *want* to run `getSoupRecipe` and `hireSoupChef` at the same time but rather sequentially (with the result of one being the input of the other), which is why your original `Promise.all` code doesn't work.

Comment: Also, `Promise.all` doesn't "run" anything. What's starting the actions are the calls to `buySoupPan()` and `getSoupRecipe()`, which both happen immediately, causing the asynchronous tasks to run concurrently. What `Promise.all` does is only to wait for all results of the promises created before.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense